# Creating a MultiPolygon field that includes multiple

Tags: arcgis-pro, layers, fields-attributes, coordinates, data-management

I have been tasked with creating a new **polygon** layer to include lat/long of atleast 5 vertices. I have a sample of the fields of another customer they work with and I cannot seem to find out anywhere how to get that **"geometry"** field and each tier below it with the **"type"** **"Multipolgyon"** and the 5 sets of lat/long coordinates following.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are showing a json format, explore reading that format.

Comment: Is the code you posted an image?  If that is the case could you add it as a text on your post?